# How to change the malloc.c header contents?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, malloc

Before the user data area begins there are some header contents in the memory block allocated by using malloc.

```
buffer = (char*) (malloc (i));
int j;  
for(j=1;j<9;j++){
printf("before data: %d\n",*(buffer-j));
```

Output what i got is
before data: 0
before data: 0
before data: 0
before data: 35
before data: 0
before data: 0
before data: 0
before data: 0

I would like to have an extra field in the header which I will be using to set some values. I have tried modifying malloc.c library for setting up custom header but nothing worked. I would like to know if there is any way I can do this.

Comment: Just call the real `malloc` to allocate a bit more space than you need, store whatever you want in the extra space, and return a pointer to the first byte you didn't use. (Respect alignment requirements.) On `free`, or `realloc`, you'll need to adjust pointers appropriately.

Comment: What you want to change in header? You understand that the definition of `malloc()` isn't in the header file, right?

Comment: @souravGhosh i downloaded malloc.c library compiled and linked with existing binaries

Comment: @SouravGhosh He's talking about in memory data header to manage allocation space...

Comment: You don't use `malloc()` in C++ for better, i believe.

Comment: If your using `malloc()` in C++, your doing something very wrong.

Comment: Why do you ask, and what is your actual motivation?

Comment: How exactly is reading data outside the allocated block of compressed/uncompressed data going to help you with that? It is just as if you have lost the key to your house, and in search for it you go digging through random trash cans in a city where neither you nor your key have ever been. I would guess that you are rather looking for a struct which contains a flexible array member at the end...?

Comment: @Fulan Which makes even less sense.

Comment: @Fulan: you should improve your question by editing it. Comments are only for others, you need to edit your question. And you look very confused!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch now i got it. i thought there is header field in every block allocated by malloc.so there was this confusion.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès answer helped! thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains an undefined behavior as you try to access memory you didn't allocate. It may happens, on a given platform, that the memory allocator put the header just before the allocated memory but you can't rely on such.

Create your own memory de-allocation routine to add some more space before, as:

```
void *my_malloc(size_t s) 
   char *p = malloc(s+what_you_need);
   if (p!=NULL) return (void *)(p+what_you_need);
   return (void *)p;
}

void my_free(void *p) {
    free(((char *)p)-what_you_need);
}
```

You may also keep attention on alignment requirement.

Comment: Should be `return (char*)p+what_you_need;` since `+` is not defined on `void*` pointers (even if GCC has that as an extension)

Comment: Right, I will  change it.

Comment: thank you :) @Jean-BaptisteYunès

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace malloc, you can do that. Look at how it is done in tcmalloc and jemalloc and do that in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

> Before the user data area begins there are some header contents in the memory block allocated by using malloc.

This is wrong, or could be wrong in general.

A clever `malloc` implementation often handle differently blocks of various sizes. Sometimes, the bytes just before the `malloc`-ed zone are not used by the `malloc` implementation.

A possible way of implementing `malloc` might be to reserve several different large blocks (e.g. by [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ing megabytes sized segments) and handle differently small allocation and larger ones, and comparing addresses (against the boundaries of these segments) to compute sizes.

In particular, some `malloc` implementations are handling allocation of two words cells specifically. They could determine (in their `free` implementation) the size of a zone e.g. by comparing addresses. For example, a `malloc` might be coded with the (simplistic) hypothesis that all addresses of the form 0x10yyyyyy where `y` is an arbitrary hex digit are heap allocation of pairs of words. Of course the details are much more complex in real life, but you got the idea: computation of the size of a heap allocated zone does not have to use some prefix data, it can be done with other ways.

And several `malloc` implementations do handle `malloc` of two-words sized cells (very often used for linked lists, or for Lisp "[cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons)" cells) particularly.